# AsyncTask is not functioning on my second fragment connected to Mysql database on swipe

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, swipe

I have an app with three fragments which I need to Asynctask every swipe. But it seems that the Asynctask runs only on the opening of the app. But when it's already created, only the first and third fragment functions well when it comes to AsyncTask the second doesn't change when I update the database.

This is my **MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.RadarOperationMonitoringSystem;

    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

    /**
     * Created by Lemueloodle on 2/12/14.
     */
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
        ViewPager Tab;
        TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
        ActionBar actionBar;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            Tab = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
            Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(
                    new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                            actionBar = getActionBar();
                            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);                    }
                    });
            Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
            actionBar = getActionBar();
            //Enable Tabs on Action Bar
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener(){
                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                                            FragmentTransaction ft) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                    Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

                }
                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                                            FragmentTransaction ft) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }};
            //Add New Tab
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("FirstFragment").setTabListener(tabListener));
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("SecondFragment").setTabListener(tabListener));
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("ThirdFragment").setTabListener(tabListener));
        }
    }
```

This is my **TabPagerAdapter**

```
package com.example.RadarOperationMonitoringSystem;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

/**
 * Created by Lemueloodle on 2/12/14.
 */
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch(i) {

            case 0:
                return new FirstFragment();
            case 1:
                return new SecondFragment();
            case 2:
                return new ThirdFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 3; //No of Tabs
    }
}
```

This is my **FirstFragment.java**

```
package com.example.RadarOperationMonitoringSystem;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View first = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_frag, container, false);

// get the listview
        ((TextView)first.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("SecondFragment");

        return first;
    }

}
```

**SecondFragment.java**

```
package com.example.RadarOperationMonitoringSystem;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SecondFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static final String url = "http://10.0.2.2/radaroperations/networkstatus.php";

    private static final String TAG_SITENAME1 = "siteName1";
    private static final String TAG_NETSTAT1 = "netlink_stats1";
    private static final String TAG_FORECAST1 = "forcasting_stats1";
    private static final String TAG_MDSI1 = "pagasa_mdsi_stats1";
    private static final String TAG_PNOAH1 = "projectnoah_stats1";

   ....so on


    String site1 = "";
    String netstat1 = "";
    String forecast1 = "";
    String mdsi1 = "";
    String pnoah1 = "";

 .....so on

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View second = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_frag, container, false);
        ((TextView)second.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("SecondFragment");

        return second;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // We set clear listener

        new GetContactsb().execute();

    }



    public class GetContactsb extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }
        @Override
        public Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler2 sh = new ServiceHandler2();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler2.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject c = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    site1 = c.getString(TAG_SITENAME1);
                    netstat1 = c.getString(TAG_NETSTAT1);
                    forecast1 = c.getString(TAG_FORECAST1);
                    mdsi1 = c.getString(TAG_MDSI1);
                    pnoah1 = c.getString(TAG_PNOAH1);

                   ..so on
                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_SITENAME1, site1);
                    contact.put(TAG_NETSTAT1, netstat1);
                    contact.put(TAG_FORECAST1, forecast1);
                    contact.put(TAG_MDSI1, mdsi1);
                    contact.put(TAG_PNOAH1, pnoah1);

                   ...so on

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.clear();
                    contactList.add(contact);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             *
             */

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    getActivity(), contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item2, new String[] { TAG_SITENAME1,TAG_SITENAME2,TAG_SITENAME3,TAG_SITENAME4,
                    TAG_SITENAME5,TAG_SITENAME6,TAG_SITENAME7},
                    new int[] { R.id.sitename1, R.id.sitename2, R.id.sitename3, R.id.sitename4,R.id.sitename5,
                            R.id.sitename6, R.id.sitename7}){

                //This will change the color of the value depending on the limit given
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                    TextView netstata = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.netstat1);
                    TextView forecasta = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.forecast1);
                    TextView mdsia = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pmdsi1);
                    TextView pnoaha = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pnoah1);
....so on

                    //1 - Red = No link
                    //2 - Yellow = Delay
                    //3 - Green = Good

                    //Radar 1
                    //Network Link Status
                    if (netstat1.equals("1")){
                        netstata.setText("No-Link");
                        netstata.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                    }
                    else if(netstat1.equals("2")){
                        netstata.setText("Delay");
                        netstata.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
                    }
                    else if(netstat1.equals("3")){
                        netstata.setText("Good");
                        netstata.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                    }
                   ...so on to Radar 7

                    return view;

                };

            };

            // updating listviews
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }


    }
}
```

**ThirdFragment.java**

```
package com.example.RadarOperationMonitoringSystem;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class ThirdFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static final String url = "http://10.0.2.2/radaroperations/energyreadings.php";

    private static final String TAG_SITENAME1 = "siteName1";
    private static final String TAG_FREQUENCY1 = "Frequency1";
    private static final String TAG_ACCURRENT1 = "AC_Voltage1";
    private static final String TAG_ACVOLTAGE1 = "AC_Current1";
    private static final String TAG_FSTAT1 = "Flimitstat1";
    private static final String TAG_VSTAT1 = "Vlimitstat1";
    private static final String TAG_CSTAT1 = "Climitstat1";

   ...so on

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONObject c = null;

    String site1 = "";
    String freq1 = "";
    String curr1 = "";
    String volts1 = "";
    String fstat1 = "";
    String vstat1 = "";
    String cstat1 = "";

   .. so on

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View third = inflater.inflate(R.layout.third_frag, container, false);

        ((TextView)third.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("ThirdFragment");

        return third;

    }
    public void StartProgress() {
        new GetContactsc().execute();
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // We set clear listener



        new GetContactsc().execute();

    }
    public class GetContactsc extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }
        @Override
        public Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler3 sh = new ServiceHandler3();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler3.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject c = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    site1 = c.getString(TAG_SITENAME1);
                    freq1 = c.getString(TAG_FREQUENCY1);
                    curr1 = c.getString(TAG_ACCURRENT1);
                    volts1 = c.getString(TAG_ACVOLTAGE1);
                    fstat1 = c.getString(TAG_FSTAT1);
                    vstat1 = c.getString(TAG_VSTAT1);
                    cstat1 = c.getString(TAG_CSTAT1);

                   ...so on

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_SITENAME1, site1);
                    contact.put(TAG_FREQUENCY1, freq1);
                    contact.put(TAG_ACCURRENT1, curr1);
                    contact.put(TAG_ACVOLTAGE1, volts1);
                    contact.put(TAG_FSTAT1, fstat1);
                    contact.put(TAG_VSTAT1, vstat1);
                    contact.put(TAG_CSTAT1, cstat1);

                  ...so on 

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.clear();
                    contactList.add(contact);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             *
             */


            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    getActivity(), contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_SITENAME1, TAG_FREQUENCY1, TAG_ACCURRENT1,
                    TAG_ACVOLTAGE1,TAG_SITENAME2, TAG_FREQUENCY2, TAG_ACCURRENT2,
                    TAG_ACVOLTAGE2,TAG_SITENAME3, TAG_FREQUENCY3, TAG_ACCURRENT3,
                    TAG_ACVOLTAGE3, TAG_SITENAME4, TAG_FREQUENCY4, TAG_ACCURRENT4,
                    TAG_ACVOLTAGE4, TAG_SITENAME5, TAG_FREQUENCY5, TAG_ACCURRENT5,
                    TAG_ACVOLTAGE5, TAG_SITENAME6, TAG_FREQUENCY6, TAG_ACCURRENT6,
                    TAG_ACVOLTAGE6, TAG_SITENAME7, TAG_FREQUENCY7, TAG_ACCURRENT7,
                    TAG_ACVOLTAGE7},
                    new int[] { R.id.sitename1, R.id.frequency1,
                            R.id.accurrent1, R.id.acvoltage1, R.id.sitename2, R.id.frequency2,
                            R.id.accurrent2, R.id.acvoltage2, R.id.sitename3, R.id.frequency3,
                            R.id.accurrent3, R.id.acvoltage3, R.id.sitename4, R.id.frequency4,
                            R.id.accurrent4, R.id.acvoltage4, R.id.sitename5, R.id.frequency5,
                            R.id.accurrent5, R.id.acvoltage5, R.id.sitename6, R.id.frequency6,
                            R.id.accurrent6, R.id.acvoltage6, R.id.sitename7, R.id.frequency7,
                            R.id.accurrent7, R.id.acvoltage7}){

                //This will change the color of the value depending on the limit given
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                    TextView freqa = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.frequency1);
                    TextView voltsa = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.acvoltage1);
                    TextView curra = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.accurrent1);
                    ... so on

                    //Radar 1
                    if (fstat1.equals("1")){
                        freqa.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                    }
                    else if(fstat1.equals("2")){
                        freqa.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                    }
                    if(vstat1.equals("1")){
                        voltsa.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                    }
                    else if(vstat1.equals("2")){
                        voltsa.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                    }
                    if(cstat1.equals("1")){
                        curra.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                    }
                    else if(cstat1.equals("2")){
                        curra.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                    }

                   ... so on to Radar 7

                    return view;

            };

            };

            // updating listviews
            setListAdapter(adapter);


        }

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem like u. I think that problem is because ViewPager saves states of last and next pager, and building them before they come. Try setting tab.setOffscreenPageLimit(0). By doing that u may encounter problem that when ever u swipe pages, pages will be rebuild.